# Apache Flink : architecture question : backpressure and handling failure mode

Tags: apache-flink, backpressure

I have just started reading about Flink and wanted to know more about how Flink handles backpressure and how it handles failures when there is backpressure. I have read this blog post by data-artisans https://data-artisans.com/blog/how-flink-handles-backpressure and kind of understand the notion of buffer pools and how they deal with backpressure.

My Questions are

(1) how does watermark help in case of remote exchange (when the tasks are on different nodes and buffers are copied to the wire TCP) -- read this in the blog above.

(2) if there is a failure when the system is facing backpressure how is it dealt with?

(3) Is it just the async checkpoints that are used to recover? What does this checkpoint include?

(4) How much of the buffer pool's data state is captured in a checkpoint?

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for understanding how Flink's network stack currently behaves is this talk by Nico Kruber at Flink Forward Berlin 2018: [Improving throughput and latency with Flink’s network stack](https://data-artisans.com/flink-forward-berlin/resources/improving-throughput-and-latency-with-flinks-network-stack).

As for checkpointing, [Data Streaming Fault Tolerance](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/internals/stream_checkpointing.html) gives a pretty thorough explanation of how it works, and what data is captured in each snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for the super useful links David. 

After going through these, I am still not clear as to how watermark helps in backpressure.

Comment: I believe the term "watermark" is used in that blog post in a generic way, and is not referring to event-time watermarks. Furthermore, the network stack's flow control has been redesigned and reimplemented since then, and is now using the credit-based flow control described in the Flink Forward talk.

Comment: If you want to do a deep dive into how watermarks, checkpointing, and backpressure relate to one another, see this mailing list thread: http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Sharing-state-between-subtasks-tt24489.html#none.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again David. Will go through these